# Operator as an argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators

I'm quite new to Haskell, may be it's a stupid question.
What I want is to give to my function as an argument any operator.
For example:

```
myFunc :: a -> Int -> Int -> Boolean
myFunc operator a b = a operator b

*Project> myFunc (>) 5 2
True
*Project> myFunc (<=) 5 2
False
```

Help me in advice how to do that please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that with haskell function arguments.
In your function above, you want `myFunc` to take a function that takes two `Int`s and returns a `Bool` (*not* a `Boolean`, you must have typed that wrong). The declaration for that function would be `(Int -> Int -> Bool)`. Therefore, you can write:

```
myFunc :: (Int -> Int -> Bool) -> Int -> Int -> Bool
myFunc op a b = a `op` b
```

This defines a higher-order function that takes a function with two `Int` parameters that returns a `Bool` (and two `Int`s). You can now use it like any other function parameter!

Note that this is exactly the same as doing:

```
myFunc (#) a b = a # b
```

Or:

```
myFunc (%) a b = a % b
```

Because using infix operaters like `*` or `/`, or *any* operator composed only of special characters, without backticks is just shorthand for using them with (typing `` `/` `` every time you want to divide something would get annoying!).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `myFunc = id` would do the exact same thing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout True, but I think that op's question was an obviously simplified example, to be applied in a larger problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! True, it was my mistake, that I wrote here Boolean instead of Bool

Comment: also worth mentioning you can use actual operator names to pattern match arguments. E.g. `myFunc (#) a b = a # b`

Comment: @rampion You can, but I belive it is clearer here using explicit backticks to emphasize the fact that we are calling a function.

Comment: @Majora320 - given that OP referred to it as passing an operator, perhaps we should be stressing to them that operators are just functions with symbolic names?

Comment: @rampion I suppose you are correct, I'll edit a short section on that into the answer.

Comment: You need parens around the operator parameters. `myFunc # a b` does not parse. If it did, it would most likely (try to) define the operator `(#)`, not `myFunc` (for example, `a # b = ...` is a definition for `(#)`, not `a`). `myFunc (#) a b` will do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Your operators `#` and `%` will always have the default fixity `infixl 9`. `f (*) (+) a b c = a * b + c` and `f (+) (*) a b c = a + b * c` are the same function. The second one left-associates as `(a + b) * c`.

Comment: `\`/\`` is a syntax error. It'd be more correct to say that `(` and `)` make an operator into a function and a pair of `\``s makes a function into an operator.

Answer (score 8):

Under the hood, functions "exist" without names. Any function you define (or that is already defined in libraries), such as `myFunc` just **is** a function value, and the name just gives us a way to refer to it in other code that wants to use it. This is exactly the same as if you write `x = 3`: the value `3` "exists" independently of the name `x`, that name just gives us a way to refer to it.

Why is this relevant to your question about passing operators?

Well, as far as Haskell is concerned, operators like `>` and `<=` are *also* just nameless functions that happen to be bound to the names `>` and `<=`. The special treatment of them as operators (that you can write them infix between the arguments you're calling them on) is only about the *names*, and changes if you refer to them with different names.

There are two types of names in Haskell. Alphanumeric names (consisting only of letters, numbers, and underscores), and symbolic names (consisting only of symbol characters). If you have an expression `{1} {2} {3}`, then if `{2}` is a symbolic name (and `{1}` and `{3}` **aren't** symbolic names; otherwise you have a syntax error), then the expression is interpreted as meaning "call `{2}` on the arguments `{1}` and `{3}`". But if none of them are symbolic names, then it's instead interpreted as "call `{1}` on the arguments `{2}` and `{3}`".<sup>1</sup>

But all of this happens only with reference to the **name**, not to the functions actually referred to by those names. So if you write your `myFunc` like so:

```
myFunc operator a b = operator a b
```

Then it doesn't actually matter whether `myFunc` was called like `myFunc (+) 1 2` or like `myFunc plus 1 2`; inside the definition of `myFunc` the "operator" is referred to by the name `operator`, which is an alphanumeric name. So you put it first when you want to call it, with its arguments following.

Alternatively **you could use a symbolic name** inside `myFunc`, like so:

```
myFunc ($&^*) a b = a $&^* b
```

Again, this also works even when `myFunc` was called with a non-operator function like `myFunc plus 1 2`.

And of course, there are ways to convert either kind of name to work like the other; you can put an alphanumeric name in backticks to use it infix like an operator:

```
myFunc operator a b = a `operator` b
```

And you can put a symbolic name in parentheses to simply use it as reference to the function it's bound to (and this is in fact the only way to use an operator without providing arguments for it):

```
myFunc ($^&*) a b = ($&^*) a b
```

So basically, the only special thing you needed to know to pass an operator to your function is what you already knew: put the operator in parentheses when you call the function. Inside the definition of the function, you can write it exactly the same as any other function; the style of name you choose **in that function definition** will determine whether you call it like an operator or like an ordinary function. You don't need to know (and in fact *cannot* find out) whether it was an operator "outside" the function.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, when you have more complex expressions involving more than 3 things and multiple operators, then the rules of precedence and associativity come into play to determine exactly what's going on.